# Are .tld necessary to run sitemesh?

Tags: java, spring, taglib, sitemesh

I am running simple JSP pages (in a Spring 3.1 web app) decorated with sitemesh, but without including `sitemesh-decorator.tld` and `sitemesh-page.tld` explicitely in my project. It works.

Yet, I see sample projects explicitely including these files in a `\WEB-INF\tld` folder. Is this necessary? If yes what for?

For example, one project has a generic `taglibs.jsp` page imported in all pages. It includes:

```
...
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %>
...
```

**For the records**

There is not point into inserting:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %>
```

in a JSP page to be processed by sitemesh. This include should only appear in decorator pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to include these .tld(s) into your applicataion \WEB-INF\tld. They can be loaded directly from sitemesh.jar/META-INF directory.